# Unity 3D on Live CD - Only 2D on install

Tags: unity, 11.10, 3d

Every time I log in, Unity switches to 2D instead of 3D.

This is what I've been trying so far:

- Install proprietary drivers NVIDIA.
- `unity --reset`
- Install compiz effects
- Choose "Ubuntu" instead of "Ubuntu 2D" on login screen

I've tried to reinstall Ubuntu several times with the same result, but I've noticed that on the live cd/usb Ubuntu uses Unity 3D. But after the install it switches to 2D. I don't know what to do. Can someone please help me out here?

My computer is a [Asus U35J.](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Superior_Mobility/U35Jc/)

Comment: Can you gives more information about your hardware plz? (Namely graphics card model and chipset).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 1):

First off, I highly recommend that you put updates on, so open up a Terminal (Dash->Terminal) window, and type in it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot. If you still have problems, try this in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install unity unity-scope-musicstores unity-common unity-place-applications unity-lens-music unity-place-files unity-lens-files unity-services unity-greeter unity-asset-pool unity-lens-applications unity-lens-gwibber ubuntu-desktop compiz compiz-core
```

Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to my computer. Here is how I fixed it.

```
sudo apt-get install unity #to make sure it's installed

rm -R .config/compiz-1 .compiz-1 .gconf/apps/compiz-1 .gconf/apps/compizconfig- #delete any bad config files

unity --reset # reset unity
sudo reboot # reboot computer
```

And if it does not work, then I do:

```
sudo unity --reset # reset unity as root might not be a good idea but it worked for me

sudo reboot # reboot computer
```